# Не работает wi-fi на ноутбуке после установки linux debian

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

После установки долго мучился с wi-fi . Читал разные форумы. Но ничего не смог сделать. (Возможно я тупой) .Просто это мой,так сказать,первый опыт с Linux. И я не смог разобраться. У меня стоит RTL8723AE.И я вроде бы как нашел драйвера на него. Но это не помогло.Я приложу выводы всех команд которые необходимы. Если это вам поможет решить мою проблему. Очень надеюсь на понимание.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
root@xydozhnik:/home/xydozhnik# ifconfig
enp0s16f0u1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.42.203  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
        inet6 fe80::9014:95ff:fe1d:bae1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 92:14:95:1d:ba:e1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4409  bytes 2147341 (2.0 MiB)
        RX errors 5  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5330  bytes 1688432 (1.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 44:8a:5b:40:42:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 26  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 628  bytes 50272 (49.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 628  bytes 50272 (49.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f6:95:3c:11:84:c2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Замените скриншот на текст и покажите вывод с `lspci -vnn -d 14e4:`

Comment: Ничего не выводит.

Comment: По инструкции пробуйте установить: https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x

Comment: wlp1s0 не он ли?

Comment: Сделал все как в инструкции написано. Все равно не работает.
# ifconfig wlan0up
wlan0up: error fetching interface information: Device not found.И при команде iwconfig.Так же не видит wlan0 или wlan1.

Comment: А когда пишу "iwlist wlp1s0 scan" выводит "no scan results".

Comment: *iwlist* использует старый интерфейс, а вот *iw* -- новый.

Answer (score 2):

Некоторые карточки требуют прошивки для нормальной работы.

Добавьте non-free в /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

Потом

```
apt update
apt install firmware-realtek
```

Я обычно добавляю ещё firmware-linux

```
apt install firmware-realtek firmware-linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужное вам устройство — wlp1s0 (не wlan0, не wlan1 и уж точно не wlan0up).
Его и конфигурируйте через виджет управления сетями